# Import data using API and httr (GET function) library

Tags: r, api, httr

I want to import data using `httr` library using the code below. However, it gives strange output, which is not satisfied according to input in `RequestTokenBody`.

Additionally, there is a direct link, which works perfectly (and output using `httr` should be the same) -
https://ummapi.nordpoolgroup.com/messages?messageTypes=TransmissionUnavailability&statusActive&IncludeOutdated=false&publicationStartDate=2022-09-27&publicationStopDate=2022-10-28&areas=10Y1001A1001A39I

How can I import the same output as in a link , but using httr library?

```
library(httr)

url_message <- "https://ummapi.nordpoolgroup.com/messages" 

#get response
RequestTokenBody <- list(messageTypes = "TransmissionUnavailability",
                         status = "Active",
                         publicationStartDate = "2022-09-27", #"eventStart": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                         publicationStopDate = "2022-10-28",
                         IncludeOutdated = "false",
                         areas = "10Y1001A1001A39I"
                         #limit = "1"
                         
                         )

RequestResponse <- httr::GET(url_message,
           #add_headers(Authorization = paste0(" Bearer ", token)),                
           body = RequestTokenBody,
           encode = "json")


TokenContent <- httr::content(RequestResponse, "parsed", "application/json", encoding="json")
TokenContent
```

Comment: What exactly is strange about the output? The link you provided passes parameters via the querystring but your code is trying to JSON encode the data in the body. It's not clear if your API endpoint supports that or not. For the same request, use `RequestResponse <- httr::GET(url_message, query = RequestTokenBody)`

Comment: It should be as json format. here is an example, but idk why it is not working if I add new entries to the request body. https://developers.nordpoolgroup.com/reference/umm-api-messages-search

Comment: Well, you seem to be parsing the data so R will return named lists and vectors for the data. Did you want to see the raw JSON text? If so, then don't request the "parsed" values, just ask for the "text" value. It's not clear from your description exactly what isn't working